# can't install google map control in ASP with NuGet

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, visual-studio-2012

When I click install in the NuGet packages manager the screen looks like it flashes for a split second and does nothing, if I look in installed packages there are no packages installed. However it does add this line to the web.config file

```
<add tagPrefix="artem" namespace="Artem.Google.UI" assembly="Artem.Google" />
```

since the package is not installed properly I can't use the artem map control. I have created a new project and installed it fine so it is something in my current project that I need to change that is not allowing me to get it installed. The things I have done so far:
1. Browsed to the packages file in my project and deleted the GoogleMapControl.6.1 folder.
2. Removed the  line from the web.config folder.
3. Removed the reference to Artem.Google in my project.
4. Cleared package cache which had google maps file in it.- Manage Nuget Packages - Settings - PackageManager - General - Clear Package Cache.

Then tried to reinstall from manage Nuget Packages - Google Map Control.
Now I click install and it looks like it installs ok has a green tick next to it, then I try and add a :

```
 <div>
   <artem:GoogleMap ID="GoogleMap2" runat="server"></artem:GoogleMap> 
  </div>
```

GoogleMap is not a know element, no Artem tools in the toolbox and if I go to the package manager and click on installed packages, there is nothing there. So it is not installing fully somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I followed to fix the problem

1. Browse to the packages file in the project and delete the GoogleMapControl.6.1 folder.
2. Remove the line from the web.config folder.
3. Remove the reference to Artem.Google in the project.
4. Clear package cache which has google maps file in it.- Manage Nuget Packages - Settings - PackageManager - General - Clear Package Cache.
5. Delete the packages.config file
6. install with the Package Manager Console run:

PM> Install-Package GoogleMapControl -Version 6.1.0

7. Add <%@ Register assembly="Artem.Google" namespace="Artem.Google.UI" tagprefix="artem" %> to top of asp page where the maps will be used.
8. Add  to body of this page.